# Jboss 7 and eclipse indigo plug in giving error while starting server?

Tags: eclipse, java, jboss7.x

I installed  Eclipse indigo and jboss 7 server and jboss server plugins installed for struts2 application.

I created simple application with jsp page and deployed in to jboss7  server ( i installed server ,run from out side of eclipse and i saw new features of jboss 7 ) after deploying application .
I want  to start the server but server giving error like " Error:no server JVM at c:\java\jre1.6\bin\server\jvmdll"

help me for this issue.

thanks
param

Answer (score 1):

change jvm in jboss's tomcat conf from

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Comment: In my system java C:\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin\client dir has  files jvm.dll Xusage.txt , classes.jsa
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin\server  has jvm.dll Xusage.txt
it is already there but giving error.

Comment: your server is pointing to `c:\java\jre1.6\bin\server\jvm.dll` make it  point to `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`

Comment: This works but I'd rather set the JAVA_HOME / JDK JBoss uses in the launch configuration - does anybody know the option for this?
Sadly, JBoss Tools ignores the parameters in jboss.conf so you have to set them separately in Eclipse / Server runtime settings.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and did not find where I could set the JVM for JBoss in Eclipse Indigo. I got JBoss 7 working by removing the JRE6 from installed JREs in Eclipse and only having JDK6 there. I also changed JRE6 to JDK6 by double clicking the JBoss server -> Open launch configuration -> Classpath -> Bootstrap Entries.

After this I readded JRE6 to Eclipse for the projects that used it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the below answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941796/no-server-jvm-at/11561914#11561914)

I've just been struggling with this same problem in Eclipse and I noted that as suggested by the answer above the [JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/thread/171560) site has a thread on this issue saying the same as the answer above to copy files from the jdk to the jre folder.

I noticed that you can avoid having to do this if you define the runtime to be the jdk when you create the server. I didn't find how to edit an existing server though.

[image: eclipse Screenshot]