# datanode and namenode service not started

Tags: windows-7, hadoop, cygwin

**I am using window 7 with cygwin** After installing **hadoop 1.1.1** when i am starting service than problem arise ***JAVA_HOME path not set** and many more....
Commmand : bin/start-all.sh

[image]

but when i type **bin/hadoop version** command than return right version and i am also set java environmental path..

plz suggest me what is the problem..

Comment: Did u set Java_Home environment variable in ur system properties? If so, can u specify the value?

Comment: yes i set environment variable in system properties....

Comment: @ruchi give the more details of your process....

Comment: @dev problem solve using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941796/no-server-jvm-at

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you have sent the Java environment itself. This link suggest to change hadoop-env.sh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325594/working-with-hadoop-localhost-error-java-home-is-not-set kindly check the same.

Comment: Does `echo $JAVA_HOME` display a proper value?

Answer (score 0):

You should set $JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc file.